# Errors when running Java Application (maven project) from command line (outside eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop

I need to run a project from a machine without eclipse. So Instead of doing "Run Java Application" within eclipse, I did the following from command line:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.myproject.myJob" -Dexec.args="/Users/edamame/part-r-00006 myOut"
```

---

However, I got the following error, what did I miss in my command line? Thank you very much!

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project myProject: An exception occured while executing the Java class. org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project myProject: An exception occured while executing the Java class. org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3040)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3010)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1776)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

---

The error complains org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job is not found, but I do have it in my pom.xml like below. Did I do anything wrong in my pom.xml?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.argparse4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>argparse4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xmlenc</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlenc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-el</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.java.dev.jets3t</groupId>
                <artifactId>jets3t</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.sf.kosmosfs</groupId>
                <artifactId>kfs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>oro</groupId>
                <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
                <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.javadocmd</groupId>
        <artifactId>simplelatlng</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hadoop-core has scope as provided in your pom.xml, that means maven is assuming that you will provide this jar somehow on classpath yourself, which you are not doing here. So, either remove the provided tag or add the jar to classpath when running the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with delete all the libraries in .m2 folder and again run mvn clean and  mvn install.